# Python List comprehension: Add Element to a list if condition in another list (with same length) is true

Tags: python, list, boolean, list-comprehension, cluster-analysis

Let's say I have an array:

```
a =  [0.42, 0.18, 1.54, 2.9, 1.81, 2.35, 0.18, 1.54, 2.92]
```

which has the following (element-wise) logical state:

```
[False, True, False, False, False, False, True, False, False]
```

Is there a nice way to use a list comprehension to only add the True elements to a new list?
Additional question:
True elements from a shall be popped out afterwards (as they are now already processed)

Comment: `zip` both of them e,g `[v for v, state in zip(a, logical_state) if state]`. If it's a numpy array you could do `a[logical_states]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```py
>>> a =  [0.42, 0.18, 1.54, 2.9,  1.81, 2.35, 0.18, 1.54, 2.92]
>>> b = [False, True, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False]
>>> c = [num for num, truth_value in zip(a, b) if truth_value]
>>> c
[0.18, 0.18]
```

**Edit:**
**Q-** what `c = [num for num, truth_value in zip(a, b) if truth_value]` this line does ?
**A-** above line is equivalent to following code:

```py
c = list()
for num, truth_value in zip(a, b):
    if truth_value:
        c.append(num)
```

**Q-** what is `zip()` in python?
**A-** you can read about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp)

if still anyone wants more explanation to understand just let me know from comments.

Comment: Works just fine.  Regarding my additional question: I guess updating "a" such that now only the previous "False" values remain would require and additonal line with "if not truth_value" condition right?

Comment: yes you are absolutely right, just don't forget to assign it to "a", kindly consider accepting my answer by clicking on tick mark on my answer so that i can earn reputations , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide an alternative, this can also be done using [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) (Python 3.1 or later). `compress(a, b)` makes an iterator which provides elements of `a` whose corresponding element in `b` evaluates to true.

For example:

```
>>> a =  [0.42, 0.18, 1.54, 2.9, 1.81, 2.35, 0.18, 1.54, 2.92]
>>> b = [False, True, False, False, False, False, True, False, False]
>>>
>>> c = list(itertools.compress(a, b))
>>> c
[0.18, 0.18]
```

It would still be necessary to remove those elements from `a`, either using a list comprehension, or the same technique, but flipping the boolean values, which is somewhat less elegant:

```
a = list(compress(a, (not x for x in b)))
```